# react-select: Overwrite default styles and remove the clearable 'x' icon

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

Thank you for opening this question. I implemented the [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

```
            <Select
              searchable
              clearable
              name="form-field-name"
              options={options}
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
```

When changed the page to `RTL`, I had some space (`padding-right`) at the beginning of the selected option. The screenshot attached clarifies that. I tried to add

`.has-value.is-clearable.Select--single > .Select-control .Select-value {
    padding-right: 10px;
}`

to my own CSS but that didn't work out. please help me fix it.

Another problem, the 'x' that clears the text I couldn't find a way to remove it, the problem is that it neither clears the text nor it could be removed. I used both ways with/without `searchable` property. Also, it generates an error when clicked because null value returned (I figured that out using console). Please take a look at the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Updated the post!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure about your first question.

To remove 'x' set the `isClearable` props to `false`.

```
<Select
  searchable
  isClearable={false}
  name="form-field-name"
  options={options}
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The official answer to your first question is to create a custom style and override the native react-select styles like this:

> (I think you have to override `valueContainer`, but I leave you other props you can play with)

```
const AutocompleteStyles = {
    control: (defaultStyles: any) => ({
      ...defaultStyles,
      padding: '0',
    }),
    option: (defaultStyles: any, state: any) => ({
      ...defaultStyles,
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: '#dcdcdc4c',
      },
    }),
    singleValue: (defaultStyles: any) => ({
      ...defaultStyles,
      padding: '0',
    }),
    valueContainer: (defaultStyles: any) => {
      return {
        ...defaultStyles,
        padding: '0',
      };
    },
    placeholder: (defaultStyles: any) => {
      return {
        ...defaultStyles,
        padding: '0',
      };
    },
    dropdownIndicator: (defaultStyles: any, state: any) => {
      return {
        ...defaultStyles,
        padding: '0',
      };
    },
    indicatorSeparator: (defaultStyles: any) => {
      return {
        ...defaultStyles,
        display: 'none',
      };
    },
  };
```

Then, assign those styles to you react-select component like this:

```
<Select
        ...
        styles={AutocompleteStyles}
      />
```

As you see, you can receive two props inside the method, first one are the default styles and the second one is the react-select state, in case you would like to handle styles based on component state (Like if you have a selected value or is empty).

For more info, you can check react-select styled component:
https://react-select.com/styles